# Blender 4.0 bpy create links using "group.interface.new_socket"

Tags: python, shader-nodes

I am having difficulty creating a link using the new method of creating sockets in Blender 4.0's python api. More details on the changes here, while it doesn't cover links or the issues I'm having: https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/4.0/Python_API

My question is: How do we access the "NodeSocket" type needed to create links from the "NodeTreeInterfaceSocketType"?

Error message from example code below:

> ```
> Error:
> TypeError: NodeLinks.new(): error with argument 1, "input" -  Function.input expected
> a NodeSocket type, not NodeTreeInterfaceSocketFloat
> ```

Example Code:

```
group = bpy.data.node_groups.new("group_name", type='ShaderNodeTree')
nodes = group.nodes
links = group.links    
input_node= nodes.new(type='NodeGroupInput')
#Example math node to link to
math_node = nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeMath')
Input_1 = group.interface.new_socket(name='Input Name', in_out='INPUT', socket_type='NodeSocketFloat',)
links.new(Input_1,math_node.inputs[0])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new interface API is for only node tree sockets not for node sockets. When you create one it is already in `NodeGroupInput`.

```py
import bpy

group = bpy.data.node_groups.new("group_name", type='ShaderNodeTree')
nodes = group.nodes
links = group.links

input_node= nodes.new(type='NodeGroupInput')

math_node = nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeMath')

Input_1 = group.interface.new_socket(name='Input Name', in_out='INPUT', socket_type='NodeSocketFloat')

links.new(input_node.outputs[0], math_node.inputs[0])
```

`NodeGroupInput` is a node inside `ShaderNodeTree` that exposes the node tree input socket that you create with `interface.new_socket`.

`ShaderNodeTree` interface inputs are the outputs of the `NodeGroupInput` inside it.